# Fast Filter of Array With Respect to Another

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, filter, count

Suppose I have an array of indexes, `A`.
Suppose I have an array `B`, where every key is an array containing some indexes or number.
I would know which of the entries in `B` contain some index appearing in `A`.
For example (in php style):

```
A = [3,45,67,8]
B = [ 1 => [1,6,81],
      2 => [5,67,3,4,5,66,6],
      3 => [55,56,57,58],
      4 => [45,80,81,82]
    ]
```

The entries of B which contain some value of A are 2 and 4.
So the function I would make should be:

```
function solution = filter(A,B) // solution = [2,4]
```

Now, with a brute loop, looping over entries of B, the complexity will be
`O(nm)`, where `n` is `#B` and `m` is the size of longest row in B.
There are smarter solutions?

Comment: Why isn't `1` a qualifying key? It contains `8` which is in the whitelist.

Comment: yes you're right...

Comment: You have to loop through every entry of `B`. it can't get better than that.

Answer (score 2):

Edit #2:

### By moving all values to be compared to key positions, php can more than double efficienct (by my demo's system time metric).

Furthermore, if you have duplicate values in your subsets, calling `array_flip()` will reduce the size by disallowing duplicate keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6aLJD))

```
$A = array_flip($A);  // prepare for key comparisons    
$result = [];
foreach ($B as $key => $haystack) {
    if (array_intersect_key(array_flip($haystack), $A)) {
        $result[] = $key;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Edit:

Whenever you want to optimize array searching with php, it is often best to try to prepare your data in a way which allows php to leverage its strength with hash tables.  https://codedmemes.com/lib/best-performance-array-intersection/

Consider this preparation...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lHie7))

```
foreach ($B as $key => $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $hay) {
        $C[$hay][] = $key;
    }
}

var_export(array_keys(array_flip((array_merge(...array_intersect_key($C, array_flip($A)))))));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 4,
)
```

- The nested `foreach()` loops generate a collection of subarrays which have unique values from `B`'s subarrays as keys and `$B`'s original keys as new subarray values.
- `array_intersect_key()` checks the keys which php does much faster than checking values. (see first hyperlink article)
- Then `array_merge(...)` flattens the subarrays into a single 1-dim array.
- Finally `array_flip()` and `array_keys()` removes duplicates and re-indexes the results.

---

I don't know exactly how `array_intersect()` works its magic in terms of efficiency, but this is probably how I'd go about it:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OgtDn))

```
$A = [3,45,67,8];
$B = [ 1 => [1,6,8],
      2 => [5,67,3,4,5,66,6],
      3 => [55,56,57,58],
      4 => [45,80,81,82]
    ];

$result = [];
foreach ($B as $key => $haystack) {
    if (array_intersect($haystack, $A)) {  // generate an array with co-existing values
        $result[] = $key;  // add key if array_intersect makes a non-empty array
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 4,
)
```

---

I suppose if there is a "downside" to using `array_intersect()` it would be that it will bother to make multiple matches, when only a single match per row is necessary.  For this reason, `array_search()` or a `break`ing loop might have advantages.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HHi6g))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($B as $key => $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $hay) {
        if (in_array($hay, $A)) {
            $result[] = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);  // same result
```

Comment: I think the complexity is still O(nm), because array_intersect is linear with the size of the array. The second choice is much better, but the worst case is still O(nm)...

Comment: `break` reduces `m` in qualifying cases.

Comment: @giuseppe I've added a new technique to the start of my answer.

Comment: beside the fact that you can use isset() in a similar way, I think nothing change wrt complexity: the worst case is stille O(nm), agree?

Comment: More times than not, when I post answers involving array searching, I use `isset()` because it is the fastest way.  As the hyperlinked article describes, searching keys is much faster, the cost in this task is in the data preparation.  So you will need to decide for yourself if the cost of preparation outweighs a brute force approach -- you will need to benchmark your actual project data.

Comment: @giuseppe One last edit.  I think the cleanest and fastest way will be to flip `$A` then iterate `$B` and flip each subarray and use `array_intersect_key()` to check for matches.